# Listening for messages in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to listen for text messages from the application. I followed steps described at http://www.gadgetsaint.com/android/read-sms-messages-android/ yet I am unable in the application to receive the messages. I tried on both android emulator and real phone yet still not getting message. Any suggestions (I am targetting API > 21 and my phone is android 7)?

PS: I tried few more samples yet still no luck

Comment: Did you grant yourself the necessary permissions on the test phone as well? Also it's hard to debug without the code sample.

Comment: I already figured out: none of this examples was accounting for runtime permissions check. As soon as I added permission check it worked.